# reestablish root shell

Tags: shell, sudo, root, aix

I disabled the shell of user root with the command `chuser shell=/bin/false root` and now I cannot switch to root with `sudo su -`. PermitRootLogin is disabled too, so I don’t know how could I reestablish the shell of the root user. Any advice?

Comment: You learned that it was a bad idea. Get a live system and fix `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Goro, i have access to my user's terminal, and can type commands but cannot switch to root

Comment: What kind of sudo access do you have?

Comment: You can try `sudo bash` and then running `chsh` or just `sudo chsh` and hope it'll work. Either way, consider this a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Any other user around who has the permission to edit `/etc/passwd` and could change the shell back to the original entry? Or any chance to boot the machine into single user mode, if need be with a rescue disk?

Comment: I have another 3 users in system group(root's group),but i am not sure if one of those could help

Comment: Any normal user won't have write access to `/etc/passwd`. Any normal user won't be able to start a root shell. Single user mode will try to start root's shell. Someone who has stared a root shell before it was changed could change it back.

Answer (score 0):

For what i can read here:
[Learn the files first, then the commands](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixuseradmin/index.html)
and here:
[chuser Command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/chuser.htm)

you should type:

```
sudo chuser shell=/usr/bin/ksh root
```

**PS:** *Don't play with the root account unless you know what you are doing and why?*